# Write a Optimal program to remove numbers from a string and then result string should be reversed

Tags: javascript

Write a Optimal program to remove numbers from a string and then result string should be reversed for e.g Input = "A1B2"  Output = "BA" in any language

the program which i came up with is this

```
var str = "A1B2";
var temp = "";
for(var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(!(str[i] >= 0 && str[i] <= 9))
        temp += str[i]
}
```

Comment: `java != javascript.`

Comment: Did you want to ask a question?

Comment: And what is the question ? And how could we possibly come up with an answer which works with any language ?

Comment: In any language ???? No it doesn't exist.

Comment: What does "optimal" mean? Shortest code, fastest execution, smallest memory usage, or...? `input.replace(/\d/g,'').split("").reverse().join("")` does it in one line...

Comment: @SanketMakani yea i know "java != javascript " the reason i tagged java here becoz u r free to write in any language u desire whether its java or any other language .... Just write code becoz the above code i came up with my Boss wasn't happy with it !!

Comment: *"my Boss wasn't happy with it"* - Well the code shown contains a syntax error and won't run, so maybe that's why.

Comment: Ok thank you everyone for your valuable comments here ...
can anyone here can come up with solution in C lang  ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "A1B2"
str.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[0-9]/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, You need answer in any language.

In java,

```
String str="A1B2";
String answer = new StringBuilder(str.replaceAll("[0-9]","")).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: See [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) if you don't understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You start at the last position of the input and check if it is a number, if it is, then skip it, otherwise, add it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = reader.readLine();
    String newWord = "";

    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (input.charAt(i) < '0' || input.charAt(i) > '9') {
            newWord += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(newWord);
}



Input: 
B224SA54ABCR

Output:
RCBAASB
```

Comment: yea right that's what the program which i wrote above is same but My boss seems to be not happy with this code so thats the reason i came here if there could be more better solutions to this !!

Comment: These two programs aren't same. You have compared chars with numbers instead of char codes - in C your output will be same as input.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate char by char in your string and detect wether the current char is a letter or not, may be by using [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). The reserving will be done by iterating from the end on the string to the beginning as you did in the shown code. At least this is what I would do in C, but other easier ways exist in java.
You should not use `temp += ""`if temp has not been initialized prior. I cannot recommend you any method or function to do so " in an optimal way since it depends on the language.

Here is a possible C solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char line[128] = "A1B2C9C841630ERV221";
char res[128] = "";
for (int i = strlen(line) -1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (isalpha(line[i]))
    {
        char currentChar[2];
        currentChar[1] = 0;
        currentChar[0] = line[i];
        strcat(res, currentChar);
    }
}
printf("%s\n", res);

Output : VRECCBA
```

Only thing you should care of is the size of `line` and `res` which I set to 128 which might not be enough depending of the length of the string you input.

Comment: i know temp was not initialized  that was a typo mistake anyways thanks for your time